# how to show date picker on link click with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a simple process to be able to select a day and have it set as a get parameter.  I cannot get the jquery datepicker to show up.

Here is what I have:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>

{{ date }} - <a href="#" id="datepicker">Change Date</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936229/open-datepicker-by-clicking-a-link

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936229/open-datepicker-by-clicking-a-link

Comment: you must do some research before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Len_D.  The answer can be found here by someone else who already asked this question:

[Open Datepicker by clicking a Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936229/open-datepicker-by-clicking-a-link)

```
<input id="hiddenDate" type="hidden" />
<a href="#" id="pickDate">Select Date</a>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#hiddenDate').datepicker({
        changeYear: 'true',
        changeMonth: 'true',
        startDate: '07/16/1989',
        firstDay: 1
    });
    $('#pickDate').click(function (e) {
        $('#hiddenDate').datepicker("show");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```